# Printing integer from a file

Tags: c

I face some issues while reading a file of integer. I'd like to print on my terminal every integer from a file (input.txt). input.txt is constructed with one integer per line.

Input.txt:

```
1234
234
9083
8738
34
345678
30920
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <zconf.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
   int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
   if(fd == -1){
      printf("Error with input file\n");
      return -1;
   }
   struct stat buf;
   int fstatTest = fstat(fd, &buf);
   if (fstatTest == -1) {
       printf("Error with fstat\n");
       return -5;
   }
   int* map = (int*) mmap(NULL,buf.st_size,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
   if(map == MAP_FAILED){
      close(fd);
      printf("Error with mmap");
      return -4;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < buf.st_size/sizeof(int); i++){
      printf("%d\n",map[i]);
   }
   if((munmap(map,buf.st_size)<0)){
      close(fd);
      printf("Error with munmap\n");
   }
   if(close(fd) <0){
       printf("Error while closing input");
       return -4;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But what I have in my terminal is not the same as in my input.
I have this :

```
875770417
875770378
942684426
926419507
856307763
875760180
943142453
959460106
```

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: Looks like you have a text file with numbers in it. You're trying to read it as if it was a binary file with ints in it.

Comment: The *string* `"345678"` is a six-byte sequence of characters. The *`int`* value `345678` is a platform dependent four-byte (typically) sequence of bits.

Comment: ...which can be verified by looking at your first output number `875770417` which in hex is `34333231` which is ASCII bytes for `"1234"` little-endian, your first text string.

Comment: `mmap` is completely the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: `int i; FILE *fp = fopen ("input.txt", "r'); while (fscanf ("%d", &i) == 1) printf ("%d\n", i);` or `char line[256]; FILE *fp = fopen ("input.txt", "r'); while (fgets (line, sizeof line, fp)) fputs (line, stdout);`